# Can any caching DNS servers refresh their cache asynchronously?

Tags: caching, dns, low-latency, dnsmasq

We run a latency-sensitive system. We found one significant cause of latency: some processes were making blocking DNS lookups to remote nameservers. To mitigate this, we have installed a local caching DNS resolver, specially `dnsmasq`.

But we still see occasional significant pauses where queries to the local DNS cache (`dnsmasq`) can take a long time. These are caused by TTL expiry; in these cases `dnsmasq` queries its upstream server before responding to the local process.

We would like to eliminate these pauses, too. I would like our local DNS cache to always respond immediately, even if the response is stale. The cache should query its upstream server asynchronously. For example, if the cache serves a stale response, it could refresh this asynchronously. Or a more sophisticated policy would be to refresh the cache asynchronously shortly before the TTL expires.

But I can't find any such setting for `dnsmasq`, or for any other caching DNS servers I've looked at. Are any DNS servers designed to run in this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

[Knot resolver](https://knot-resolver.cz) with configuration `modules = { 'predict' }` [will start](http://knot-resolver.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules.html#prefetching-records) asynchronous refresh of records that are put into answer at a moment when their TTL is close to expiration.

Note that version 2.0.0 has a bug that defeats this refresh for records without DNSSEC signatures (will be fixed in the next release).

Comment: Thanks! I haven't heard of Knot before. I'll have to check it out.

Comment: `unbound` has also a `prefetch` option to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unbound DNS Server also does this with a prefetch option - yes/no.